# Exception in getting xpath to a web element: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "a"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is a dropdown with 9 options in it, all of anchor (a) type. Selecting an option from the list, changes its class & other attributes dynamically.

This is how the html code looks like:

```
<select data_old_value="Email" id="ActionType-db5ff710-2a01-11e8-9c5f-22000aa79843" name="ActionType-db5ff710-2a01-11e8-9c5f-22000aa79843" onchange="RuleWizardIns.RuleActionChanged($(this))" style="width: 103px !important; height: auto !important; display: none;" aria-disabled="false"><option value="Email" selected="selected">Send Email</option><option value="TaskCreate">Create Task</option><option value="AddActivity">Add Activity</option><option value="AddToList">Add To List</option><option value="LeadUpdate">Update Lead Fields</option><option value="TagLead">Tag Lead</option><option value="StarLead">Star Lead</option><option value="UnStarLead">Unstar Lead</option><option value="Webhook">Call Webhook</option></select>
    <option value="Email" selected="selected">Send Email</option>
    <option value="TaskCreate">Create Task</option>
    <option value="AddActivity">Add Activity</option>
    <option value="AddToList">Add To List</option>
    <option value="LeadUpdate">Update Lead Fields</option>
    <option value="TagLead">Tag Lead</option>
    <option value="StarLead">Star Lead</option>
    <option value="UnStarLead">Unstar Lead</option>
    \<option value="Webhook">Call Webhook</option>
</select>
<span>
    <a class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-dropdown" id="ActionType-db5ff710-2a01-11e8-9c5f-22000aa79843-button" role="button" href="#nogo" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="ActionType-db5ff710-2a01-11e8-9c5f-22000aa79843-menu" style="width: 103px;" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Send Email</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
        <span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Send Email</span>
        <span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
    </a>
</span>
```

I tried to get the control on **Update Lead Fields** option by using below code, but unfortunately its not working.

```
Select ActionType = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@data_old_value='Email']/following-sibling::span/a")));        
ActionType.selectByVisibleText("Update Lead Fields");
```

I'm getting below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "a"
```

And there is no ui for select attribute as you can see from below image:

https://d24cdstip7q8pz.cloudfront.net/t/t20170511180558/content/common/images/Untitled.png

Comment: The _HTML_ you shared is incorrect. You have closed the second `<select>` tag which have no starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A Select object can only be created by getting the WebElement with tag is "select" that's what the errormessage is about. I created an C# example which I tested giving expected result.

```
Driver.Url = ("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-
US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select");

var valuesSelectElement = Driver.FindElement(By.Name("select"));
var selectElement = new SelectElement(valuesSelectElement);
// To select an option by value
selectElement.SelectByValue("value1");
// To select an option by text
selectElement.SelectByText("Value 2");
var options = selectElement.Options;
//To click on one of the options
foreach (var option in options)
{
     if (option.Text.Equals("Value 3"))
     {
         option.Click();
     }
}
```